# how to load list of values to modal popup

Tags: java, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I'm Korean. 
Please understand that I can't speak English very well.

I'm making a modify modal and i want to load a list of values to modal
 (or call?)
I made the modify modal but I dont't know how to load a list of values to Modal.
Please guide me how to load it.

```
<a class="btn btn-warning mx-1 mt-2" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#updateModal" >modify</a>


<% 

int evaluationID=0;
if(request.getParameter("evaluationID")!=null){
evaluationID=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("evaluationID"));
}

System.out.println("아이디"+evaluationID);
EvaluationDTO evaluationUpdate = new 
EvaluationDAO().getList(evaluationID);
%>

<div class="modal fade" id="updateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="modal" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: @ScaryWombat  please confirm  above source again

Comment: Sorry I do not know about `bootstrap` but the normal way is for a servlet to prepare the data, which can be passed either via a parameter or via runtime using ajax.  If passing as a parameter then you can load using EL or if by ajax use javascript.  There maybe a bootstrap way to do it, but I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
List<Map<String, Object>> students = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
Map<String, Object> s1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
s1.put("name", "jim");
s1.put("age", "15");
students.add(s1);
Map<String, Object> s2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
s2.put("name", "lucy");
s2.put("age", "12");
students.add(s2);
request.setAttribute("students", students);
```

%>

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>age</td>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${student.name}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${student.age}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't speak English very well TOO